# I can't for the life of me figure out why my C program is crashing

Tags: c, binary-tree

I have an assignment for uni in which I have to implement a binary search tree. It has to take information and write that to disk, and keep an index stored in the tree. However, whenever I call a function that has to do with the tree, the program crashes. The following code snippets are my bTree.h file, and the code which causes the crash.

```
/* binary tree ADT */

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define DATA_LENGTH 12
#define POS_LENGTH 8

struct INFO
{
    char data[DATA_LENGTH];
    int filePos;
};

struct NODE
{
    struct INFO data;
    struct NODE *left;
    struct NODE *right;
};


/* 
format for index data file

data identifier     12 bytes
position in file    8 bytes
--end of record--   total 20 bytes

*/

/* 
 Given a binary tree, return true if a node 
 with the target data is found in the tree. Recurs 
 down the tree, chooses the left or right 
 branch by comparing the target to each node. 
*/ 

int lookupPos(struct NODE *node, char target[]) 
{ 
    int length = strlen(target);

    // 1. Base case == empty tree 
    // in that case, the target is not found so return false 
    if (node == NULL) 
    { 
        return -1; 
    }        

    else 
    { 
        // 2. see if found here, in which case return file pos. 
        if (strncmp(target, node->data.data, length) == 0)
        {
            return node->data.filePos;
        }       

        else 
        { 
            // 3. otherwise recur down the correct subtree 
            if (strncmp(target, node->data.data, length) < 0)
        {
            return lookupPos(node->left, target);
        }

            else 
            {
                return lookupPos(node->right, target); 
            }
        }    
    } 
} 


/* 
 Give a binary search tree and a number, inserts a new node 
 with the given number in the correct place in the tree. 
 Returns the new root pointer which the caller should 
 then use (the standard trick to avoid using reference 
 parameters). 
*/ 
struct NODE *insert(struct NODE *node, char info[], int pos) 
{ 
    int length = strlen(info);
    // 1. If the tree is empty, return a new, single node 
    if (node == NULL) 
    { 
        struct INFO stuff; 
        strncpy(stuff.data, info, DATA_LENGTH);
        stuff.filePos = pos;

        node->data = stuff; 
        node->left = NULL; 
        node->right = NULL;

        return(node); 

    }    

    else 
    { 
        // 2. Otherwise, recur down the tree 
        if (strncmp(info, node->data.data, length) <= 0) 
        {
            node->left = insert(node->left, info, pos); 
        }

        else 
        {
            node->right = insert(node->right, info, pos);
        }

        return(node); // return the (unchanged) node pointer 
    } 
} 

struct NODE *loadTree(char filename[]) //cIndex.dat for customers, pIndex.dat for products
{
    struct NODE *node;
    char data[DATA_LENGTH];
    char posStr[POS_LENGTH];

    FILE* file; 
    file = fopen(filename,"rb");

    char c;
    fseek(file, 0, SEEK_SET);

    while((c = fgetc(file)) != EOF) //reads until EOF char
    {
        fseek(file, -1, SEEK_CUR); 


        fread(data, sizeof(char), DATA_LENGTH, file);
        fread(posStr, sizeof(char), POS_LENGTH, file);

        insert(node, data, atoi(posStr));

    }       

    fclose(file);

    return node;
}

int saveTree(struct NODE *node, char filename[], int posInFile)
{
    FILE *file;
    file = fopen(filename, "r+b");

    char c;
    char posStr[POS_LENGTH];

    fseek(file, posInFile, SEEK_SET);

    while((c = fgetc(file)) != EOF)
    {
        fseek(file, -1, SEEK_CUR);

        fwrite(node->data.data, sizeof(char), DATA_LENGTH, file);
        sprintf(posStr, "%d", node->data.filePos);
        fwrite(posStr, sizeof(char), POS_LENGTH, file);

        posInFile = ftell(file);

        saveTree(node->left, filename, posInFile);
        saveTree(node->right, filename, posInFile);
    }

    fclose(file);

    return 1;
}

int getSize(struct NODE *node)
{
    if (node==NULL) 
    { 
        return 0; 
    }

    else 
    { 
        return( getSize(node->left) + 1 + getSize(node->right)); 
    } 
}
```

And now the offending code snippets:

```
int filePos = getSize(tree);
```

and

```
insert(tree, cust.id, filePos);
saveTree(tree, "cIndex.dat", 0);
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Do you have access to a debugger?  Wouldn't that be the most helpful advice someone could give you?

Comment: please provide a complete, compilable program (main(), etc.)

Comment: In addition to what paddy said, `data identifier     12 bytes` you don't have space for the 0-terminator in your `struct NODE`.

Comment: The program compiles, no errors whatsoever. The only indictation that something's wrong is that the program crashes.

Comment: @MattGrima That it compiles only means the syntax is correct. Crashing is a matter of semantics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never allocate memory.  In your `insert` function:

```
if (node == NULL) 
{ 
    struct INFO stuff; 
    strncpy(stuff.data, info, DATA_LENGTH);
    stuff.filePos = pos;

    node->data = stuff; 
    node->left = NULL; 
    node->right = NULL;

    return(node); 

}
```

"If `node` is `NULL` then start assigning stuff to it".  Yikes!

What you need to do is this:

```
node = malloc( sizeof(struct NODE) );
```

---

And the other thing I see as a major issue is this:

```
struct NODE *loadTree(char filename[])
{
    struct NODE *node;
    ...
}
```

You must initialise `node` to `NULL` because you use its value inside `insert` later on.

And Daniel Fischer has already pointed out that your strings in `loadTree` may be one byte too short (thus you cannot reliably call `strlen` and related string functions on them).

Comment: Added the malloc(), yet it still crashes.. something else is wrong

Comment: You did add it *before* you assign stuff to `node`, right? =)  Anyway, in the bigger picture it looks as if you have written the whole program at once rather than testing parts of it.  Without seeing your `main` function to get an idea of how you are calling your other functions, and so it's hard to know what other problems you may have.

Comment: Hmm, I just had a second skim through.  In your `loadTree` function, you declare an uninitialised `node`, then pass that into your `insert` function.  Its value won't necessarily be NULL, so you immediately have a problem, that your function thinks you passed it a tree but it's just rubbish.  Bad things will then happen.  Make sure you initialise it to `NULL` before you use it, and then have a think about whether you are creating a tree at all, or just a bunch of completely isolated nodes.  You will have to think carefully about the return value from `insert` and how you use it.

Comment: I had tested all the other parts of the program, the only problematic area is this binary tree..  I know for sure that int filePos = getSize(tree); is the culprit, yet I don't see why.

Comment: That might be the problem! Just initialised it to null, now seeing if it works.

Comment: No worries.  Happy coding.  And in future, never underestimate the power of `printf` (or a debugger) for tracking down problems yourself... =)